# Subtracting hours from Get-Date/DateTime Object

Tags: powershell

I'm studying fundamentals on Powershell to avoid some silly misconceptions so I'm working on some misc projects. I want to take the Cisco Interval Values (15 minute intervals over 24 hours = 96 intervals) and output the time of the error.

For instance, if the interval in question is 2 and it is 11:00 AM currently, the interval time would be yesterday at 11:30 AM.

What I have thus far is just the equation, but I'm not sure how to get the DateTime object to a point that I can manipulate it for the equation.

```
$myInt = Read-Host "Interval Number";
$lapsed =  ([int] $myInt - [int]96) * [int]15 / 60
$currentTime = Get-Date
```

If possible, I'd like to essentially take my current time, subtract the number of hours, then create a new time from that.

**Solution Code:**

```
$myInt = Read-Host "Interval Number";
$interval =  ([int] $myInt - [int]96) * [int]15 / 60
$currentTime = Get-Date 
"Current time is: $currentTime"

$elapsedTime = $currentTime.AddHours(-$lapsed)
"Interval $myInt reported at $elapsedTime"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution was using [AddHours()](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/SECURITY/en-US/53572fe9-1e9b-4ade-880d-25c0c3bbb59a/powershell-adding-hours-to-time-provided-by-argument-not-getdate?forum=ITCG) `Get-Date.AddHours()` to subtract the number of hours elapsed in the intervals.

```
$myInt = Read-Host "Interval Number";
$interval =  ([int] $myInt - [int]96) * [int]15 / 60
$currentTime = Get-Date 
"Current time is: $currentTime"

$elapsedTime = $currentTime.AddHours(-$lapsed) ## Subtract the value of $lapsed from $currentTime
"Interval $myInt reported at $elapsedTime"
```